# Text within CSS Transitions

Tags: html, css, transition

When you hover over the box there is a triangle and I'm trying to put the text "project 1" inside the triangle, but for some reason it keeps going outside of it. I feel like I just might be missing something.

Also the triangle isn't suppose to have a straight edge to the right, the text makes it like that.

```css
.img {
  width: 310px;
  height: 225px;
  background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/33mphuh.png");
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 0 0 200px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.img:hover .hover {
  bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-family: avenir;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="hover">
    <h2>project</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if the answer helped, you could mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `h2` element is properly contained inside an element which has a `200px` border-left applied . So it seems to be outside, but it is actually inside the `.hover` element, to the right of its parent border

You may position your heading with `position: absolute` and move it to the left, over the border
as in this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/nr5aeyvm/

---

relevant CSS

```
h2 {
    font-family: avenir;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffff00;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: -180px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason your project text is getting pushed out is because you're using `border` to create the transparent effect. The project text is contained inside the body of the element. So like Fabrizio suggested you can either position it absolute position or negative margin to pull it back over into the side.

Another option would be to make the triangle and the project block siblings of eachother and transition both up.